# Optimizing value of one variable in a function in R to get 0 mean error

Tags: r, function, optimization

I have a function calculating mean error (of postop refraction). I want to optimize value of A variable to get mean error = 0. Could you help me with that? I tried reading about optimize and optim functions but I have no idea how to make it work. Sample code:

```
Constants <- list(IOL = list(A_to_pACD_a0 = -63.896, 
             A_to_pACD_a1 = 0.58357,
             A_to_S_a0 = -65.60,
             A_to_S_a1 = 0.5663,
             pACD_to_S_a0 = -3.595,
             pACD_to_S_a1 = 0.9704,
             A_to_ACD_a0 = -68.747, 
             A_to_ACD_a1 = 0.62467))
set.seed(123)
num_rows <- 100

L <- sample(22:26, num_rows, replace = TRUE)
K <- sample(40:45, num_rows, replace = TRUE)
A <- 118
I <- sample(16:28, num_rows, replace = TRUE)
SE <- runif(num_rows, min = -4, max = 4)

df <- data.frame(L, K, A, I, SE)

Mean.Error <- function(L, K, A, I, SE) {
  ACD <- Constants$IOL$A_to_pACD_a0 + Constants$IOL$A_to_pACD_a1 * A
  ELP <- 0.292 * L - 2.93 + (ACD - 3.94)
  Ref <- (1.336 / ((1.336 / (1336/(L-ELP-0.05)-I)) + (ELP+0.05)/1000)) - K
  results <- SE - Ref
  result <- mean(results)
  return(result)
}
Mean.Error(df$L, df$K, df$A, df$I, df$SE)
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: What is `Constants`?

Comment: Sorry, I added Constants now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing your metric function somewhat to only have one parameter

```
Mean.Error <- function(A) {
  ACD <- Constants$IOL$A_to_pACD_a0 + Constants$IOL$A_to_pACD_a1 * A
  ELP <- 0.292 * df$L - 2.93 + (ACD - 3.94)
  Ref <- (1.336 / ((1.336 / (1336/(df$L-ELP-0.05)-df$I)) + (ELP+0.05)/1000)) - df$K
  (mean(df$SE - Ref))^2
}
```

you can do

```
optimise(Mean.Error,lower=0,upper=200)

$minimum
[1] 118.8344

$objective
[1] 4.489538e-13
```